# Funcion para todos los checkbox

Tags: javascript, html

Buen dia. Necesito hacer una función que sirva para todos los checkbox de un formulario, esta función debe de crear un input con el id igual al id del checkbox seleccionado y al deseleccionar el checkbox se debe eliminar el input.

tengo la siguiente función pero no me funciona correctamente.

```
    $(function() {
    $("input[type='checkbox']").click(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked') ) {
            var y = $("input:checked").attr("id");
            var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
            x.setAttribute("type", "text");
            x.setAttribute("value", "Hello World!");
            x.setAttribute("id", y);
            document.body.appendChild(x);
            y = "";
        }else{
            console.log('adios');
        }
    });
});
```

con esto genero el input y le coloco el id identico al del checkbox pero si selecciono otro checkbox mientras hay otro seleccionado, toma el id del primer checkbox que se selecciono. Espero puedan apoyarme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En lugar de seleccionar el input chequeado, utiliza `this` asi:

```
 $(function() {
$("input[type='checkbox']").click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked') ) {
        var y = $(this).attr("id");
        var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
        x.setAttribute("type", "text");
        x.setAttribute("value", "Hello World!");
        x.setAttribute("id", y);
        document.body.appendChild(x);
        y = "";
    }else{
        console.log('adios');
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Excelente resultado alanfcm Muchas Gracias hermano!!

Comment: me funciono bastante bien pero, cuando quiero ponerlo dentro de un div solo puedo poner uno y ya no me permite dar click en otro checkbox ni en ninguna parte. Agregue var div = document.getElementById("inputs"); y div.appendChild(x);

Comment: Te recomiendo que no uses el mismo id para identificar a mas de un elemento.  Puedes agregar `input` al id cuando crees el input.  Ademas, creo que no existe ningun elemento con el id "inputs".

Comment: "inputs" es el nombre que le di al div donde estarían los inputs creados y si tomare tu consejo de cambiar el id a los nuevos inputs